# When Clip.open() is called, there is a java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -4. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, javasound

Here is my method below to play a sound:

```
void playMusic(String musicLocation) {

    try {
        File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);
        if(musicPath.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file found");       
            AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInput);
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press ok to stop playing");
            
            
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Can't find file");
            System.out.println(musicLocation);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This method is called from another class with:

```
String filepath = "suss.wav";
Music musicObject = new Music();
musicObject.playMusic(filepath);
```

When I run it, I first get `file found` and then the error message:

```
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1130)
    at mod.Music.playMusic(Music.java:26)
    at mod.Overseer.<init>(Overseer.java:35)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

What does this mean and how would I fix it?

Comment: Your code is fine. I can execute your code and play a .wav file in my system successfully. One reason I  think of is the audio device problem. is your audio device enabled? can you able to play the audio directly using a player without using the code?

Comment: Looking at the DirectAudioDevice source code it looks like there is probably a problem with your wav file contents leading to the code calculating a negative length.

Comment: Could you share which java version you are using, there seem substantial differences in the code `com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice.java` between jdk8, jdk11 etc.